# What happens at the end of Final Fantasy VII?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I finally beat *Final Fantasy VII* after about 45 hours, but the end video leaves more questions then answers. My question is, did the gang die or did they survive the accident?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may make as many questions as it answers, but [Advent Children](http://na.square-enix.com/dvd/ff7ac/) was the follow up to FF VII

Comment: Unfortunately, *Advent Children* was absolutely terrible.

Comment: yea, sure the plot wasn't the strongest ever in a movie (basically imagine an average RPG boiled down into a 90 minute film) but in standard SquEnix form it did look pretty and was mostly fun to watch

Comment: @JSBangs I disagree.  Aside from a couple cheesy scenes I thought it was really well done.

Comment: @JSBangs: I also think it was a good movie in it's own way. You can clearly see how SquareEnix was trying to fix it's mistakes they did with `The Spirits Within`. While `The Spirits Within` was not much of a Final Fantasy, `Advent Children` was too much of it.

Comment: Be sure to watch the `Complete` version, and not any of the other (less than complete) versions.

Comment: And dont't forget Blue Moon anime part of Advent Children (which happens before FFVII)

Answer (score 19):

Aeris' dialogue with the planet activated Holy, the ultimate White magic that is the only magic powerful enough to combat Meteor, the ultimate black magic.

Holy used the planets lifestream to defeat Meteor, rescuing the planet and it's people.

Midgar was left in ruins.

All of the Main characters of FF7 survived and lived to fight another day (Advent Children).

Sephiroth's physical form no longer exists having been destroyed by Cloud and the gang, but his presence still infects the life stream, the planet and Cloud's mind.

A number of Sephiroth clones still exist.

That leads to the story of Advent Children.